# printf on the same line with Perl

Tags: perl, formatting, printf

I'd like my printf function to write the output to a file like this:

```
name      age      gpa
```

Instead, it's written like this:

```
name
age
gpa
```

Here's my code, all help is greatly appreciated.

```
printf FILE "%-0.25s %3s %4s\n", @get_name, @get_age, @get_gpa;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values probably contain newlines. Use `chomp` to remove them. Also, it is safer to use scalar values, not arrays, as parameters to `printf` - otherwise, if there is more than one value in @get_name, @get_gpa will not get printed:

```
chomp for $get_name[0], $get_age[0], $get_gpa[0];
printf FILE "%-0.25s %3s %4s\n", $get_name[0], $get_age[0], $get_gpa[0];
```